# Can I use regular expression in cucumber step where I validate string?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, gherkin

Ex - Then the message should contain:
| {any string} Hello |
Is there some kind of syntax I have to follow so that it use it as regular expression instead of text ?

The step definition is in Ruby for"Then the message should contain"

Referred this - https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/ , but didnt figured it out

Comment: The documentation you've linked says that you can use `{}` to match any string. Did you try that? If it didn't work, then what unexpected error/behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: For a more advanced custom parameter type (but from the sound of it, I don't think you need to do this!), check the docs here and click the "ruby" tab: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/configuration/

Comment: Yes tried tht, it didnt worked , i used ".*" and it worked , the link you sent also suggest similar